# Sharing or Sending complex Data to Coldfusion From Java

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am writing JavaClass which reads Excel files and it creates a Collection object.
What will be the best possible options to pass a Structure from Java to Coldfusion?

Comment: Just curious: are you on ColdFusion 9 or Railo? If so, you may want to check out the spreadsheet functions and tag that were added in v9 (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html) ... and Railo has matching functions and tags that have been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the java class return a [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). CF will automatically [convert it to a structure](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7884.html) which can be used with any of the CF structure functions.

That said, Craig makes a good point. If you are using CF9 or Railo, both have spreadsheet functions available. You might want to investigate using those rather than rolling your own.